# Polymer unresolved attribute

Tags: polymer, polymer-2.x

I am looking for documentation on Polymers *unresolved* attribute. Is there any? I am not able to find it. Is it still supported in Polymer-2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is document you're looking for. It's for Polymer 0.5.

https://docs-05-dot-polymer-project.appspot.com/0.5/docs/polymer/styling.html#fouc-prevention

Comment: Thanks, I get the idea. However, this documentation is marked as deprecated and users don't know whether that is useful for 2.0. On the other side the newest version of the shop app uses it. I will file a github issue then.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, `unresolved` attribute is not from Polymer, it is from the web components. This is just a CSS [pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes) to style elements by default.

If you would like to learn more [click here](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/customelements/#unresolvedels).

Comment: Your answer is very helpful. I did nevertheless accept Franks answer just because it is closer to my question about Polymer documentation, although the documentation is deprecated. I think it just got forgotten in the new one, so I will file a github issue.

Comment: That's not a problem.